# move_uploaded_file() function does not upload to my folder

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm making a ecommerce website with a CMS where I can edit, add products etc, when I add a product and choose and image from my computer it does not upload to my folder I made for images "uploads".

Does anyone know the solution to this, it's probably in my code but I can't seem to figure it out.

If I manually add the image to the folder uploads and choose the image when I add the product the image shows.

Here is my code:

```
function add_product() {


 if(isset($_POST['publish'])) {


  $product_title          = escape_string($_POST['product_title']);
  $product_category_id    = escape_string($_POST['product_category_id']);
  $product_price          = escape_string($_POST['product_price']);
  $product_description    = escape_string($_POST['product_description']);
  $short_desc             = escape_string($_POST['short_desc']);
  $product_quantity       = escape_string($_POST['product_quantity']);
  $product_image          = escape_string($_FILES['file']['name']);
  $image_temp_location    = escape_string($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

  move_uploaded_file($image_temp_location, UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . DS .  $product_image);


  $query = query("INSERT INTO products(product_title, product_category_id, product_price, product_description, short_desc, product_quantity, product_image) VALUES('{$product_title}', '{$product_category_id}', '{$product_price}', '{$product_description}', '{$short_desc}', '{$product_quantity}', '{$product_image}')");
  $last_id = last_id();
  confirm($query);
  set_message("New Product with id {$last_id} was Added");
  redirect("index.php?products");


    }


    }
```

The UPLOAD_DIRECTORY is a path that I have configured in a file named config.php and it looks like this:

```
    defined("UPLOAD_DIRECTORY") ? null : define("UPLOAD_DIRECTORY", __DIR__ . DS . "uploads");
```

Comment: what does http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php show?

Comment: sorry, I still don't know what to do...

Comment: add this to the top of your php files `error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1); `

Comment: Nothing, no errors, still the same problem.

Comment: You should not use this value `escape_string($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);` in `move_uploaded_file()` Use the original `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

Comment: @JessieJackson thank you so much, thats what I needed